# RichFaces and Facelets, a good combo?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, facelets

I've been programming using RichFaces and JSF for quite some time now, and like the features that Facelets offer (especially as part of JSF 2), but haven't used it yet.  Are there any gotchas to watch out for or incompatibilities between RichFaces and Facelets?  I use A4J ajax functionality a lot as part of RichFaces, so I am concerned about that also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that Facelets is just a view layer for JSF 2. JSF2 and RichFaces have some incompatibilities. Check this to see a list of them:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20

RichFaces used with standalone Facelets (I currently use 1.1.14) works great.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Richfaces 4 is going to be built on JSF 2 and I think they are reworking a lot of it, but who knows when that'll be out ;o)

Answer (score 3):

The [RichFaces demo application](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/actionparam.jsf?c=actionparam&tab=usage) uses Facelets, so I'd even say it's recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go a bit further and say that ***not*** using Facelets with JSF is crazy.

It's such a handy framework. No wonder they used many concepts from it for JSF2.

Answer (score 0):

We use them together without any problem.  I have not encountered any gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

No worry about this combination, it's definitely the way to go with JSF !

Answer (score 0):

I'm used configuration: richfaces4 + facelets + netbeans 6.9, and the only problem detected betwen facelets and rich is a two(2) click for ajax or include page dynamic